# multiple dynamic drop down lists in form

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a form with drop down lists in each row. A change in a dropdown list on column A must result in hiding the field in column B in the same row. Here is a trimmed-down version of one row in the table.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="duration">
      <select id="session_attributes_0_duration">
        <option value="0">15 minute block</option>
        <option value="1">30 minute block</option>
        <option value="2">1 hour block</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cost>
      <input id="session_attributes_0_cost">
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is my CoffeeScript where I try to hide the cost in the case of a '15 minute block'

```
set_duration_changes = () ->
  durations = find_all_duration_drop_downs()
  for duration in durations
    if duration.firstChild.tagName == "SELECT"
      $(duration).on 'change', duration, (evt) ->
        hide_cost(duration)

hide_cost = (duration) ->
  duration_in_words = find_choice(duration.firstChild)
    if duration_in_words == '15 minute block'
      cost = duration.nextSibling
      cost.style.display = "none"
```

Unfortunate the event always affects the last row in the table. I really need a strategy that explains the steps I should follow. Can anyone share with me an example of how to define an event that will occur on the SELECT element of the correct table row?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by defining a jQuery change event. I have still plenty to learn so I will not be surprised if the following code can be refactored:

```
set_session_duration_change_event = () ->
  $('.session-duration').on 'change', (e) ->
    durationList = $(this)
    durListId = durationList.attr('id')
    if !durListId 
      return
    duration_value = durationList.val();
    rowId = durListId.charAt(46)
    customDurId = 'care_service_care_service_sessions_attributes_' + rowId + '_custom_duration_4i'
    if (duration_value == "0") || (duration_value == "1") || (duration_value == "2")
      customDur = document.getElementById(customDurId)
      customDur.parentElement.className += " hidden"
    else
      customDur = document.getElementById(customDurId)
      customDur.parentElement.className = "custom-duration"
    return
```